# Cannibal eats himself, in movie or series episode

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I can't recall the name of a movie, maybe a TV series episode, where one character that was a cannibal started eating himself, so that after a while only the skull remained eating the last piece of flesh.

I know, it's creepy, but it should be a comedy or something like that.

Maybe from late 80's or early 90's, I tried googling it but the web is flooded with real life stories about cannibalism.

I'm not sure, but I think that the cannibal was some sort of savage chasing some people, he somehow put by accident a part of his body in his mouth and liked the taste, so he started eating himself.

I think the skull was shown at the end, before the credits, sucking the last piece of skin or flesh.

But again, it was funny, not creepy.

Comment: I haven't seen such a movie or TV episode, but Stephen King wrote a short story where a doctor ended up on a tiny island with nothing to eat, and I'll bet you can guess where the story goes.  It's called "Survivor Type" and I found a link to a scanned copy of the story on the web.  (It has a few spelling errors; I think it was OCR'ed and not checked over.)  http://www.krypta-smierci.neostrada.pl/ebooks/Stephen%20King%20-%20Survivor%20Type.html

Comment: There's a similar scene in one episode of Andy Hamilton's Old Harry's Game, where he orders his assistant Scumspawn to eat himself. Though it's a radio show, rather than a TV show or movie, so it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you guys, I added as much as I could recall, for clarification.

Comment: There's a selection of films and TV shows here; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Autocannibalism

Comment: Wow, I just wanted a funny weekend movie, but this is the creepiest search I've ever made on the web, no matter how many funny tags I put beside the word "cannibalism"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like "[Hard Rock Zombies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089254/)" a horror comedy from the mid to late 80s. There's a brief scene in [this YouTube trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUEK6FlOmkY) , starting at about 56 seconds, that appears to show a zombie-creature chowing down on it's own hand (with mustard) . This trailer has another scene at about 2:59 that shows the same (I think) character, now down to a just a head, eating the last flesh off of it's own skull. Unfortunately the video clip is extremely poor quality, so it's a little hard to make out (I had to view it a couple of times before realizing what I was seeing).

Comment: _(width mustard)_... thank God! Otherwise it would just be weird!

Comment: And he certainly seems to relish it.